# Disable Alt+F4 but allow the form to be closed by code, CloseReason.UserClosing is not helping

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, application-close

I want that the form will not close by doing <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F4</kbd> but if `Application.Exit()` or `this.Close` is called from the same Form, it should be closed.

I tried `CloseReason.UserClosing` but still no help.

Comment: Do you need to filter out only Alt+F4 or clicking close button as well?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If you need to filter out <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F4</kbd> event only (leaving clicking of close box, `this.Close()` and `Application.Exit()` to behave as usual) then I can suggest the following:

1. Set form's [`KeyPreview`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.keypreview.aspx)
   property to `true`;
2. Wire up form's [`FormClosing`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.formclosing.aspx) and [`KeyDown`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.keydown.aspx) events:

   ```
   private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
   {
       if (_altF4Pressed)
       {
           if (e.CloseReason == CloseReason.UserClosing)
               e.Cancel = true;
           _altF4Pressed = false;
       }
   }

   private bool _altF4Pressed;
   private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
   {
       if (e.Alt && e.KeyCode == Keys.F4)
           _altF4Pressed = true;
   }
   ```

Comment: Wonderful, Thanks a lot.
This line is very important :  if (e.Alt && e.KeyCode == Keys.F4)

Comment: And this line is very important too! Set form's KeyPreview property to true;

Answer (score 2):

It's very easy you can do it by set **SuppressKeyPress** property to true on **Form_Keydown** EventHandler as below.

```
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.F4 && e.Alt)
        {
            e.SuppressKeyPress = true;

        }
```

With this you can also close your active form by set SuppressKeyPress Property to false on same eventHandller or any other way.

Answer (score 0):

Capture Alt+F4 hotkey by setting Form's KeyPreview property to true and overriding OnProcessCmdKey method.

Answer (score 0):

How did you use CloseReason?

See the sample code here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.formclosing.aspx

You need to set the Cancel property of the passed FormClosingEventArgs object to stop the form closing.

Comment: The problem with `FormClosing` event is that Alt+F4 and calling `this.Close()` won't be distinguishable -- they both will have `CloseReason.UserClosing`.

Comment: prior to calling this.Close() set a property that can be examined in FormClosing...

Comment: this will work it you can actually control where to call form's `Close` method. What if it could be called by some third-party component at some moment?.. Also, `CloseReason.UserClosing` will be set when clicking form's close box. (It is desired behaviour?)